# With categorical data set, how does one determine whether a low frequency value is statistically valid?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, categorical-data

I'm trying to calculate whether low frequency categories in a categorical data set have a high confidence interval. As a hobbyist programmer, I'd like to add this calculation to my website.

Currently, users count discrete events until a preset total is reached (100 events... 200, 500, etc). Namely, they tally types of cells in the blood.

But, for certain low frequency events, counting too few events may yield a nonrandom tally and over-representation of this event. For a given count total, how can I get a confidence interval for the category data?

Comment: What does "statistically valid" mean?

Comment: I suppose valid in this context means that if, for example, I count 1% of a certain cell type, it reflects a likelihood that percentage will hold true if I count any more number of events. I'd suggest that less than 5% chance of error would be standard in medical applications, and would apply here.